# Using a Card as a button in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to turn a card (when you click on it), into a button that could be used to take you to another report page, in PowerBI Desktop?

Same question, but for a slicer, would it be possible, when I click on one of the selections in the slicer (list), to take me to another report page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can put invisible buttons wherever you want as a workaround with effectively the same experience for the end-user.

Comment: This is kind of working. Do you always have to do CTRL-Click for the bookmark to work, or there some other way to make it work, with a single click?

Comment: I think it should just be that way in the editor, not when published.